# Discord.py Timed message is not executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

So, I have created a command that executes a reoccurring message. I have it set to 10 seconds in the code for testing purposes, but I will have the message loop every 4 hours. I don't get any errors when running the code, but the command is not actually executing. The message never sends and I am confused as to why and can't seem to figure it out.

````
import discord
import discord.utils
import asyncio
import http.client
import aiohttp
import EZPaginator
import platform
import yaml
import os 
from yaml import load, dump
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$', intents=intents)
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ZOF BOT IS ONLINE!')

# Reoccuring Message Reminder

@tasks.loop(seconds=10) 
async def send_message(ctx):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='reminders')
    remind = discord.Embed(title='**:rotating_light:ATTENTION ZOF:', description='Do not forget to donate to Fortress, Alliance tech, and Ruins!', color=0xFFFFFF)
    print('Reoccurring Message Sent.')
    await channel.send(embed=remind) ```
````

Comment: Hey there CRM! Why do you have `ctx` as an argument in your `send_message` task loop? You can't get `ctx` from an `on_ready` event. I would recommend getting the guild via [`client.get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) or similar and finding the channel through there. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi Bagle, thank you for that information! I have fixed up the code and am now met with this error. After a lot of research, I am stuck and can't seem to get past this error. 

Here is a ghostbin link with the current code in question, along with the error it's producing. https://ghostbin.com/8bVgl

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Comment: I figured out the error for AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_message' after a lot of screwing around with the code.

I changed client.get_guild() to client.get_channel()

And also changed  await channel.send_message() to channel.send()

Comment: You need to get the channel from the guild, you can't send a message to the guild directly. For example, define your guild as `guild = client.get_guild(0000)`, then get the channel from your guild as you usually would, as `channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name="name")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start you task function for example in `on_ready` event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    if not send_message.is_running():
        send_message.start()
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, I can't believe that's what I was forgetting lol!

Do you by chance know why this error maybe populating after adding that on_ready event?

Unhandled exception in internal background task 'send_message'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: send_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'

Comment: @CRM000 `send_message` function should not take any arguments.

Comment: Thank you Ratery, So I have fixed up the argument issue, and now whenever I run the code I am met with this error :/! 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nitro\Desktop\Python\Python Scripts\ZOFBOT\ZOFBOT.py", line 42, in <module>
    @client.event()
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

Here is a ghostbin link to my current code along with the error.
[https://ghostbin.com/COFB2]

Comment: @CRM000 You should write `@client.event`, not `@client.event()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help Ratery, everything is working smoothly now :)